Tkinter on Ubuntu 24.04 segfaults
When I try to use tkinter on my Ubuntu 24.04 it segfaults ie
python3 -m tkinter
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have tried to reinstall the tk package with apt
sudo apt reinstall python3-tk tk tk8.6 tk8.6dev

But I still get the issue. I ran gdb to try to find out what it is failing on with
gdb --args /usr/bin/python3 -m tkinter

And a I get following error
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled on' to .gdbinit.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Downloading source file /usr/src/tk8.6-8.6.14-1build1/unix/../generic/ttk/ttkTheme.c
Ttk_TkDestroyedHandler (interp=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/tk8.6-8.6.14-1build1/unix/../generic/ttk/ttkTheme.c:539

I don't understand why Tkinter is trying to download some C theme file and then failing on that.

Do you have a self-built version of tk8.6 / libtk8.6 in addition to the one installed via apt?

Should be installed via apt, I have not build and installed a python with tkinter myself on the system
